# Spelling Correction in Visual Studio not working for en-us

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I use the VS spelling correction by using the Toolbar item "Toggle Spell Checker" in the Visual Studio 2022 17.9.0 toolbar.

I also added an .editor-File to my .NET MAUI Project as described in the following link with the following content:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/text-spell-checker?view=vs-2022

```
spelling_languages = en-us,de-de
spelling_checkable_types = strings,identifiers,comments
```

Unfortunately, spell-checking still does not work as you can see here

[image]

Any tips what I am still missing and doing wrong here? Windows is set in German, Visual Studio is in English.